# How to create new column that cumulatively sums to cumulative sum of existing column?

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

Using tidyverse functions, I'm looking to create a new column of data that sums up to the cumulative sum in the first column, but uses increments no greater than `incr`.

That could start with df

```
incr <- 1.5
df <- data.frame(a = c(6,0,0,2.5,0,0))
df
    a
1 6.0
2 0.0
3 0.0
4 2.5
5 0.0
6 0.0
```

then create a new column `b` using `incr`:

```
    a   b
1 6.0 1.5
2 0.0 1.5
3 0.0 1.5
4 2.5 1.5
5 0.0 1.5
6 0.0 1.0
```

I found `tidyr::uncount()` and it seemed like a function that could work, but I need to use non-integer increments. Generally trying to mutate and use vectorized functions and have put some thought towards running it `rowwise()`, but most of my ideas require iteration.

From comment below: If analogies are helpful, think of it like queued downloads. Column `a` shows you press to download 6 MB at time 1, 0 MB for times 2 and 3, then you press to download 2.5 MB at time 4. Your connection, however, can only download at the speed of `incr`. So, if `incr` is 1.5, column `b` shows what actually downloaded. You fully use that connection speed each period until you download the final residual (`1.0`) in time 6.

To better highlight the dimensionality, here's another df:

```
incr <- 1.5
df <- data.frame(a = rep(0,100),b=rep(0,100))
df$a[c(30,33,38)] = c(6,2.5,1)
df[30:39,]
     a b
30 6.0 0
31 0.0 0
32 0.0 0
33 2.5 0
34 0.0 0
35 0.0 0
36 0.0 0
37 0.0 0
38 1.0 0
39 0.0 0
```

with a desired output

```
     a   b
30 6.0 1.5
31 0.0 1.5
32 0.0 1.5
33 2.5 1.5
34 0.0 1.5
35 0.0 1.0
36 0.0 0.0
37 0.0 0.0
38 1.0 1.0
39 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Is `1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.0` your expected output?

Comment: yes, that would cumsum to the 8.5 of the first column. if the series kept going, b would continue with a series of zeros.

Comment: What about if the increament was 5? How would the results look like? What about if the increament was 0.5? Seems like there is still alot of information missing

Comment: `Incr = 5` would give `b = c(5,1,0,2.5,0,0)`. `Incr = 0.5` would give a sequence of 0.5 repeated 17 times using this examples `a`.

Comment: I still don't follow the exact logic for the output. Why do the values for `6` bleed across to the row where `2.5` is, while it then starts after the `2.5` to begin counting in increments?

Comment: Not sure if analogies are helpful, but think of it like queued downloads. Column `a` shows you press to download 6 MB at time 1, 0 MB for times 2 and 3, then you press to download 2.5 MB at time 4. Your connection, however, can only download at the speed of `incr`. So, if `incr` is `1.5`, column `b` shows what actually downloaded. You fully use that connection speed each period until you download the final residual (`1.0`) in time 6.

Comment: To clarify, df can expand to allow for smaller increments (e.g. to 17 for the 0.5 example), but doesn't shrink when the increments are larger and can fit, and the 0s from the input need to be preserved?

Comment: Correct, `df` example shown above should be considered a 6 rows slice of a significantly longer time series (think 400 rows)

Comment: Apologies, can't think of a way around this without using iteration. Each addition of a new `b` value seems to depend on both the cumsum of a and b, so not sure if there's a way of calculating this in R vector-wise before assigning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because I don't know when to give up, I think the only solution is iteration. But I think you can always do iteration in C++ to make it as super-speedy as a vectorised function:

### Edited as more efficient function (that doesn't keep calculating fresh column sums)

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "
    NumericVector iterate_to_cumsum(NumericVector v1, double incr) {
    int x = v1.size();
    NumericVector v2(x);
  
    double sumv1 = 0;
    double sumv2 = 0;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
      sumv1 += v1[i];
      v2[i] = std::min(incr, sumv1 - sumv2);
      sumv2 += v2[i];
    }

    return v2;

  }
"
)

library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(a = c(6, 0, 0, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0))
incr <- 1.5

df |> 
  mutate(b = iterate_to_cumsum(a, incr))
#>      a   b
#> 1  6.0 1.5
#> 2  0.0 1.5
#> 3  0.0 1.5
#> 4  2.5 1.5
#> 5  0.0 1.5
#> 6  0.0 1.0
#> 7  0.0 0.0
#> 8  0.0 0.0
#> 9  1.0 1.0
#> 10 0.0 0.0
#> 11 3.0 1.5
#> 12 0.0 1.5
#> 13 0.0 0.0
#> 14 0.0 0.0
```

An actually working `Rcpp` function does indeed speed things up a little (running tests as in @LMc's post):

```r
# @Andy Baxter
cpp <- function(){
  df |> 
    mutate(b = iterate_to_cumsum(a, incr))
}

# @LMc
fun_factory <- function(){
  df |>
    mutate(b = map_dbl(a, incr_cap(1.5)))
}

bench::mark(
  cpp(),
  fun_factory()
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 cpp()           1.53ms   1.77ms    474.      2.15MB     8.00
#> 2 fun_factory() 116.79ms 124.31ms      8.15  786.48KB    19.6
```

Comment: I see this working for the example I used, but when I put it in practice on a df where the first addition in `a` occurs in row 31, the `row_number()` counter has blown up too large - so everything is zero everywhere.

Comment: @LMc you're spot on, I think that's a similar issue to what I'm pointing out in my comment above

Comment: Good spot - resetting that count to zero is the missing cog here! `row_number` was perhaps a bit of a blunt instrument!

Comment: I'm trying to improve my answer but will delete it if I haven't cracked it in a few minutes :P

Comment: I've added another example df to help illustrate the issue!

Comment: I've un-deleted with a semi-useful way of doing it speedily using a C++ loop, so equivalent to vectorisation and wrapped up in one new tidyverse-style friendly function. Perhaps a bit over-complicated, but hope you enjoy it anyway!

Comment: Good checking! I had realised after I had gone to bed last night that my C++ code calculates a whole new sum every iteration rather than incrementing a saved sum which I would imagine is inherently better. But good to see that a functional like yours is actually a pretty handy method without needing to go into complicated C++

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @LMc - I've updated my function to store an iterating set of two cumulative sums rather than re-calculate column sums (oops!) and the speed is coming back into it again.

Comment: Had borrowed your tests as seemed like a good idea! Nice to see it running on your faster machine though. Thanks for checking over :D

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use a function factory. This allows you to save some state information, in this case a remainder, which is helpful for your computation. The iteration comes from within `map_dbl`, but this is not a vectorized answer:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

incr_cap <- function(incr) {
  force(incr)
  remainder <- NULL
  function(curv) {
    val <- if (is.null(remainder)) curv else curv + remainder
    if (val > incr) {
      remainder <<- val - incr
      return(incr)
    } else if (val > 0) {
      remainder <<- 0 
      return(val)
    } else {
      remainder <<- 0
      return(0)
    }
  }
}

df |>
  mutate(b = map_dbl(a, incr_cap(1.5)))
#      a   b
# 30 6.0 1.5
# 31 0.0 1.5
# 32 0.0 1.5
# 33 2.5 1.5
# 34 0.0 1.5
# 35 0.0 1.0
# 36 0.0 0.0
# 37 0.0 0.0
# 38 1.0 1.0
# 39 0.0 0.0
```

---

### Benchmark

#### Set up

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(4)

incr <- 1.5
df <- data.frame(a = rep(0,100),b=rep(0,100))
df$a[c(30,33,38)] = c(6,2.5,1)
dat <- df[30:39,1, drop = FALSE]
rownames(dat) <- NULL
df <- dat[sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)), 1E5, replace = TRUE), , drop = FALSE]

Rcpp::cppFunction(
  "
    NumericVector iterate_to_cumsum(NumericVector v1, double incr) {
    int x = v1.size();
    NumericVector v2(x);
  
    double sumv1 = 0;
    double sumv2 = 0;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
      sumv1 += v1[i];
      v2[i] = std::min(incr, sumv1 - sumv2);
      sumv2 += v2[i];
    }

    return v2;

  }
"
)

incr_cap <- function(incr) {
  force(incr)
  remainder <- NULL
  function(curv) {
    val <- if (is.null(remainder)) curv else curv + remainder
    if (val > incr) {
      remainder <<- val - incr
      return(incr)
    } else if (val > 0) {
      remainder <<- 0 
      return(val)
    } else {
      remainder <<- 0
      return(0)
    }
  }
}

# @Andy Baxter
cpp <- function(){
  df |> 
    mutate(b = iterate_to_cumsum(a, incr))
}

# @LMc
fun_factory <- function(){
  df |>
    mutate(b = map_dbl(a, incr_cap(1.5)))
}

# @benson23
for_loop <- function() {
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (i == 1 & df$a[[1]] < incr) {
      df$b[i] <- df$a[[1]]
    } else if (sum(df$a[1:i]) - sum(df$b[1:i]) > incr) {
      df$b[i] <- incr
    } else {
      df$b[i] <- sum(df$a[1:i]) - sum(df$b[1:i]) 
    } 
  }
  return(df)
}
```

### Results

```r
bench::mark(
  cpp(),
  fun_factory(),
  for_loop()
)

#   expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory     time      
#   <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>     <list>    
# 1 cpp()          954.5µs   1.15ms  797.         785KB     7.99   399     4   500.89ms <df>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
# 2 fun_factory()  77.87ms  82.38ms   12.0        783KB     4.00     6     2   500.53ms <df>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
# 3 for_loop()       1.16m    1.16m    0.0144     201GB    20.7      1  1437      1.16m <df>   <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
```

Note: the row-wise solution was excluded from this benchmark since this operation is notoriously slow on even modestly sized data frames.

Comment: Thanks for this, can't believe I wrote such bad C++ code, though it was late at night :P

Answer (score 2):

I will do it with a `for` loop with a bunch of `if` statements:

#### Set up dataframe

```r
incr <- 1.5
df <- data.frame(a = rep(0,100),b=rep(0,100))
df$a[c(30,33,38)] = c(6,2.5,1)
df <- df[29:39,]
df
     a b
29 0.0 0 # note I included first row as 0 to test
30 6.0 0
31 0.0 0
32 0.0 0
33 2.5 0
34 0.0 0
35 0.0 0
36 0.0 0
37 0.0 0
38 1.0 0
39 0.0 0
```

`For` loop and `if` statements:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (i == 1 & df$a[[1]] < incr) {
    df$b[i] <- df$a[[1]]
  } else if (sum(df$a[1:i]) - sum(df$b[1:i]) > incr) {
    df$b[i] <- incr
  } else {
    df$b[i] <- sum(df$a[1:i]) - sum(df$b[1:i]) 
  } 
}
```

### Output

```r
df
     a   b
29 0.0 0.0
30 6.0 1.5
31 0.0 1.5
32 0.0 1.5
33 2.5 1.5
34 0.0 1.5
35 0.0 1.0
36 0.0 0.0
37 0.0 0.0
38 1.0 1.0
39 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: I just realized you want tidyverse functions, if you think my answer is not useful, let me know and I'll delete it :)

Answer (score 2):

In terms of implementation, I've used @Andy Baxter's Rcpp function and it worked very well!

For future users looking to solve this with just tidyverse and no C++:
Agreeing with @Andy Baxter's conclusion that this would require iteration, I built out a workable if clunky method using `case_when()` starting with the 100 row `df` above:

```
 df2 <- df %>% mutate(a_sum = cumsum(a)) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(
     b_sum = lag(b,1,default = 0) + b,
     b=case_when(
     lag(a_sum,1,default = 0) == 0 & a_sum != 0 ~ incr,
     lag(b_sum,1,default = 0) == 0 ~ 0,
     lag(b_sum,1,default = 0) < lag(a_sum,1) ~ min(incr,lag(a_sum,1)-lag(b_sum,1)),
     .default = 0
     )) %>% ungroup() %>%
   select(a,b = b_sum)

 df2[30:39,]
# A tibble: 10 × 2
       a     b
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1   6     1.5
 2   0     1.5
 3   0     1.5
 4   2.5   1.5
 5   0     1.5
 6   0     1  
 7   0     0  
 8   0     0  
 9   1     1  
10   0     0
```